# In RSpec, using let to assign a regex creates unexpected pass/fail behavior - Bug or user error?

Tags: ruby, rspec

File with object under test: `foo.rb`

```
class Foo
  def a_string
    "abcdef8"
  end
end
```

Spec file: `foo_spec.rb`

```
require_relative "./foo"

describe Foo do
  let(:foo) {Foo.new}
  let(:my_matcher) {/^[a-z]+(\d)$/}


  # This test passes

  it "should match and pass" do
    my_str = foo.a_string

    my_matcher # <--- why does this affect the test?

    matcher = my_str.match(my_matcher)
    8.should == matcher[1].to_i
  end

  # This test fails

  it "should also match and pass but fails" do
    my_str = foo.a_string

    #my_matcher #<---- the only change between the tests

    matcher = my_str.match(my_matcher)  #<---- when called here, it behaves differently
    8.should == matcher[1].to_i
  end
end
```

`rspec foo_spec.rb`

```
.F

Failures:

  1) Foo should also match and pass but fails
     Failure/Error: 8.should == matcher[1].to_i
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for /^[a-z]+(\d)$/:Regexp
     # ./foo_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00095 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./foo_spec.rb:14 # Foo should also match and pass but fails
```

The only difference in the two tests is whether `my_matcher` is invoked.  I first noticed this problem when I was inspecting my_matcher (i.e. `p my_matcher`), but it also occurs with just invoking `my_matcher`.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Maybe it has something to do with capturing Regex data?

It seems incredibly odd behavior, especially for ruby.

For what its worth, it's an easy (if slightly less DRY) fix.  If `my_matcher` is declared in the `it` block it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug.  Can you file an issue with rspec-core?

Comment: Yes, I'll file a bug report. Any idea what's causes it?

Comment: I'm accepting Myron's answer more for his behind the scenes digging and isolating of the problem.  He created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/5123087) and brought more eyes on what is beginning to look like a ruby bug in 1.9.3 (ruby 2.0 doesn't have this issue).